# Why does iOS Safari render fixed elements differently if they have a gradient background?

Tags: html, css, ios

If a fixed element has a gradient background Safari on iOS won't render it behind the translucent address bar. Then, once you scroll down and the address bar hides, the fixed element takes a second to render where it should, leaving whatever's behind it visible.

Take this example:

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 999px;
}

.gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, orange 100%);
}

.color {
  background: blue;
}

.scroll {
  height: 9999px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed color"></div>
<div class="fixed gradient"></div>
<div class="scroll"></div>
```

This is what we see in safari. Note the blue-tinted address bar that should be red-orange tinted. I'm not too concerned about this, but it's worth noting.

[image: an iOS screenshot showing a red-orange gradient and a blue-tinted navigation bar]

Much worse is what happens when we scroll. This giant blue bar will show for a second until iOS decides to render the gradient there.

[image: an iOS screenshot showing a red-orange gradient with a large pure blue bar near the bottom of the screen]

For completeness, here's the codepen I used in the screenshots: https://codepen.io/RJWadley/pen/BavNrOO?editors=1100

I'm sure this has been noted before, but I can't seem to find a workaround. Why does safari render it this way?

Comment: I’m getting a red.-Orange tinted bar. What device and Safari version are you using? I’m on iPhoneSE iOS16.5.1

Comment: Safari is new IE. Why do you need `fixed` divs though?